# onPageFinished is not calling in android

Tags: android, android-webview

Actually `onPageFinished` is not calling when webview does not have any physical interface.I mean not view just like....

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(loadWordWebViewClient);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
```

I know it works when `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);` but Suppose I  just want to load url in service. then is it possible?